# In Javascript, why is 'while(true' slower than 'for(...)' when they are both iterating the same number of times?

Tags: javascript

Assuming that the `while(true)` will break at the same time as the `for(...)` loop, why is the `for(...)` faster?

According to [jsbench](https://jsbench.me/h3ktopms12/1), it is about **7%** slower to use the `while(true)`

Here's the code I've used in the jsbench:

Using a `while(true)` loop

```
/* generate array */
const arr = []
for(let i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    arr.push(i)
}

let i = 0
while(true){
    if(arr[i] >= 900){
        return;
        
    }
    i++
}
```

using a `for(...)` loop:

```
/* generate array */
const arr = []
for(let i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    arr.push(i)
}

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] >= 900){
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: JavaScript engines are optimised to run standard `for` loops. Note also that they are not completely equivalent. The `while` loop will run forever when there is no value in the array that fits the condition. The `for` loop will end.

Comment: @trincot is there an article explaining this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript Performance: While vs For Loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18640032/javascript-performance-while-vs-for-loops)

Comment: @Rojo, for instance [the last paragraph of this V8-contributor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53669606/5459839)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timing has to do with both your code and how JavaScript is compiled. The differences are pretty inconsequential in this example though, so testing which is faster varies each time the code is run and the results are pretty indeterministic. Generally, they should take about the same time or ever so slightly faster or slower.

**Your code**

Your `while` loop will continue simply because you have the condition set to always be `true`. You didn't include a condition to check if it should stop at any point after each iteration is complete.

Your `for` loop on the other hand has a condition that is checked every single time an iteration is complete (checking if `i < arr.length` still).

Other than that, your code is pretty much the same. They both have the same block of code, the difference is that the `while` loop increments `i` inside its code block, rather than like the `for` loop that increments `i` *after* its inner code block.

The differences in this case are pretty inconsequential.

**Compilation**

If you've ever studied some assembly code, you should be a little familiar with some of the structures for loops.

Depending on how the code is compiled determines which operations/instructions are run in what order. Also, the structure for a `while` loop should usually be different from a `for` loop in assembly, meaning that there may be an extra instruction to run in a `for` loop versus a `while` loop or vice versa depending on the programming language.

Comment: Since the for loop has more instructions to run, shouldn't it be slower than the while?